# Fetching two tables with search keyword

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables 'movies' and 'series' I want to fetch in these two tables in the same time with a keyword

So I try to do it but I get an SQL error

```
$query = $_GET['keyword'];
$query = htmlspecialchars($query);
$stmt = "SELECT series.title, series.pic FROM series UNION SELECT mov_title, mov_pic FROM movies WHERE mov_title LIKE '%$query%' OR title LIKE '%$query%' ";
$result = $pdo->query($stmt);
```

Comment: Please add the error message that you get to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT series.title, series.pic FROM series WHERE title LIKE '%$query%' 
 UNION
SELECT mov_title, mov_pic FROM movies WHERE mov_title LIKE '%$query%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `UNION` up in a derived table:

```
select * from
(
    SELECT series.title as mov_title, series.pic FROM series
    UNION
    SELECT mov_title, mov_pic FROM movies
) dt
WHERE mov_title LIKE '%$query%'
```

BTW, perhaps you should consider `UNION ALL` instead?

Comment: this is a terrible one.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, it is? How come?

Comment: I suppose a database would have to put both tables in a temporary table first

Comment: @YourCommonSense, well, honestly I don't know MySQL that well.

Comment: that's the problem with answers on Stack Overflow

Comment: @YourCommonSense, would UNION ALL make any MySQL difference?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT title, pic FROM series WHERE title LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute(["%".$_GET['keyword']."%"]);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT mov_title, mov_pic FROM movies WHERE mov_title LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute(["%".$_GET['keyword']."%"]);
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    $result[] = $row;
}
```

No sql injection, no database overkill

Answer (score 0):

The part before union of your query is not finished. Try like this;

```
SELECT series.title, series.pic 
FROM series where title LIKE '%$query%'
UNION 
SELECT mov_title, mov_pic 
FROM movies WHERE mov_title LIKE '%$query%'
```

Comment: but i want to add more rows how i can do it